# Correct pattern using Angular $resource to get related data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I understood that the concept of $resource in AngularJS is to return

- A resource, an object representing this resource (get, update, delete)
- A list of objects representing this resource (query)

I am using a backend which does not provide all needed information in one shot.

For example: `/User/:id`

`user = User.get({id: userId});` returns a User. Great.

If I need to get the number of his friends, I have another request wich will be like:

`/User/:id/count=friend`

And return:

`{ count: 17 }`

Here I am stuck, I can't use my `user` variable, or I will lose my user object. Plus the result will be a number, which does not represent my user anymore.

The 'dirty' way would be to go back with `$http` for this and to assign the result to `user.friendsNumber = data.count`.

But still not clean, if I `user.$put()` something, I lose my `user.friendsNumber` as it will be reassigned.

What is the correct way to handle this properly?

Comment: Declare a custom action ? `$resource(url, [paramDefaults], [actions], options);`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the action like so, and I believe additional parameters just become regular get variables.

```
angoApp.factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/User/:id', {
    id: '@id'
  }, {
    countFriends: {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {
        count: 'friends'
      }
    }
});

...

User.$countFriends({id:123});
//This should call /User/123?count=friends
```

Comment: No problem for adding custom actions and doing requests, this is currently what I am doing. But I feel like this is not clean.
What I am interested is to assign more properties like `countFriend` to a parent `user` ressource (already resolved), which I am sometimes updated, so losing properties I newly assigned like `countFriend`.

Comment: So it sounds more like you're looking for persistence like local storage?  Resource manages a CRUD, but maintaining the response data is just a matter of how you handle that object.